# IDEA JetBrains IntelliJ - Compile error on 'make' but fine when compiled using Maven and no errors reported by IntelliJ in the class file

Tags: java, maven-2, intellij-idea, compilation

So I have a maven module (module-A) in IntelliJ. I recently moved some classes from it into another new maven module (module-B) and added a dependency to it. Once I had done this I also modified the signature of a method of one of the moved classes (now in module-B).

I re-imported the poms so that IntelliJ would pick up the dependency changes and ensured all Java imports for the affected files were correct again. Now when I attempt to run my webapp (which depends on the two modules) I get a compile error in a class in module-A calling the modified method of the class in module-B.

The error message is basically saying that that method doesn't exist but believes the old method still exists! I click on the 'make' error and it takes me to the line in a class in module-A calling the modified method...the weird thing is, IntelliJ knows it is fine in the file. i.e. The method is not underlined in red like a compile error would normally be, but the class file name is :(

I compiled it from the command line using 'mvn install'  (having also installed module-B) and it is all successful. I have deleted the classes directory in the target of both  module-A and module-B and also invalidated IntelliJ's caches and restarted...still happening...any ideas?

Comment: Have you rebuilt and redeployed your whole project?

Comment: Yes tried rebuilding the whole project in IntelliJ multiple times and keep getting the same error...:(

Comment: Does clearing your IntelliJ caches help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just stated it up this morning and it's all working!

Last night what I did do was open a new project (intelliJ project) from module-A's and module-B's parent pom and successfully got it to build, possibly doing that and then opening my original project again fixed it somehow...very annoying though

Comment: I also did the same in the end. The cache wasn't working.

Answer (score 50):

I found out that this might help:

> File -> Invalidate Caches

Comment: Be careful with doing this though. See the warning on this page: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/cleaning-system-cache.html

Comment: IMHO, the comment by @Noremac should be included in the answer.

Answer (score 23):

Maven Projects -> Reimport should help.

Comment: Thanks vibneiro but I had already done that, and mentioned that in the question; "I re-imported the poms so that IntelliJ would pick up the dependency changes"

Answer (score 21):

I spent a few hours on this same issue. All of the cleans in the world didn't help.

I deleted my out and target directory in my project and recompiled - that cleared it.

Edit: There is also a magic feature under the file menu: "Invalidate Caches / Restart" This fixes a bunch of "intellij is confused" problems.

Comment: This worked for me. I think IntelliJ gets hung up on previous versions of code that have been made. Just went through all the module directories and ran clean. Everything works again!

Comment: Neither `mvn clean` nor invalidate caches & restart works for me :(

Comment: This is what fixed it for me. Thanks.

Comment: I wish I could give you more points for this,. I spent close to an hour on this issue. Damn!!!!

Answer (score 7):

Change "Java Compiler" setting in IDEA (User compiler javac in-process) to fix the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Try to `mvn clean` your projects and `mvn install` your project B.

The maven integration with intelliJ is kind of buggy when you use the make command directly provided by Intellij. You should directly use the mvn commands, or start them from the maven panel.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, unfortunately I have already tried multiple clean / installs of those modules and of their parent pom, also performed clean install.

Comment: The only thing that worked for me. What a pity, that it took a long time. =(

Answer (score 4):

I ran across a very similar problem that was driving me insane.

My code would compile fine with the ant task I normally run, but it would not build in IntelliJ, complaining about "Cannot Find Symbol blah blah"

Turns out, you can add "Excluded" files for the compiler. My file somehow got added to that list.

This list is located in File > Settings > Compiler > Excludes (IntelliJ 13)

Answer (score 4):

Following steps should fix this problem :

1. **delete** .IntelliJIdea12 / .IdeaIC12 older under c:/user/.../
2. Invalidate Intelli's cache: **File > Invalidate Caches**.
   This re-indexes your workspace on start-up and also **clears your local history**. Before you do this, **commit or back up** all your uncommitted changes.
3. Once your workspace is back after indexing, do a **maven clean install**.
4. when the build is successful, click on **Maven Re-imports**

**This worked for me**, I think it should work for others too with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior I see is similar to the one described by the original author.
Error markers show up on the right side of the editor in Intellij 14 and less so in 13.

This happens also if using Scala instead of Java and using SBT instead of Maven.

Also noticed this occurs after the second project is loaded. The first is always fine.
(After much trial and error) Figured it might be caused by Intellij's internal caches becoming somehow corrupt. "Invalidate caches" worked sometime and sometimes did not.

I work with a number of projects using Play! Framework and they use different versions of Scala and lots of dependencies.
I hypothesized the caches become corrupt because the internal key Intellij uses is not good enough to handle situations when the same class, loaded multiple times in different jars, has different signatures, and this results in the editor errors while external builds work fine.

Then the "Changing Ivy Cache Location for sbt projects in IntelliJ IDEA?" post gave the idea to segregate the ivy cache SBT and Intellij use in the hope that the ivy path is part of the internal cache key.

Paul Phillips of TypeSafe provide the "SBT extras" tooling and here I found a way to instruct SBT to use a project based ivy home, cache and SBT boot:

https: //raw.githubusercontent.com/paulp/sbt-extras/master/sbt

declare -r noshare_opts="-Dsbt.global.base=project/.sbtboot -Dsbt.boot.directory=project/.boot -Dsbt.ivy.home=project/.ivy"

- How to configure Intellij
  : see http://content.screencast.com/users/SemanticBeeng/folders/Snagit/media/ec8ec491-6d0c-4691-9598-916a63ba65ef/12.02.2014-08.59.png
- Then did the same for the external SBT build to work in sync
  : see http://content.screencast.com/users/SemanticBeeng/folders/Snagit/media/dcb287c4-200f-47f3-a937-42865675a22b/12.02.2014-09.01.png

Finally got rid of the user home based .ivy2 and all the contents.
To be sure Intellij does not use this folder I made it readonly.
This was a mistake. Intellij seems to silently fail resolve dependencies if you do this.

This solved the errors and believe they will not come back. :-)

If Intellij guys hear this: please test your releases (Scala, SBT, editor) with all the Play Framework templates from TypeSafe. The problem becomes apparent quickly this way.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had manually marked a directory as "Test Sources Root" but IDEA marked it on a parent Maven project. Unmarking it in File->Project structure...->Modules fixed the problem.

Comment: that was exactly my problem, I was going crazy, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue that was driving me insane. I had done all the other things mentioned in the answers above because I have used Intellij forever, but none worked. In the end I found out that in the maven projects portion of Intellij, one of my modules had been marked "ignore" a simple unignore command from the context menu did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if you are using different version of java while building outside IntelljJ. My IntelliJ had java10 and I was using java8 while building at terminal. Changing java version to IntelliJ fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar behavior. Running (Scala-)tests would always fail due to errors in unrelated java classes during the 'make' step.

It turned out, I had included a 'global' SDK library that collided with one of the dependencies from the project. A proper helpful error message only showed up after I deleted the 'make' step from the test. 
I then deleted the duplicate library, re-added the make step to the test and everything is now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today after upgrading from 12 to 13.

Later I fixed issue as I used the same name for Project and Module and looks Intellij allows this but cannot handle it correctly.

No idea why setting will impact the compilation, although there is no error in java editor. Should be a bug in version 13.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue after upgrading from IntelliJ 12 to 13. After multiple uninstalls and re-installs (of multiple intelliJ versions), numerous cleans and .m2 repository clearing, I finally figured out what my issue was.

In my intelliJ settings, the repositories mentioned in my main POM file could not be connected to. this was in turn due and alternate repository that was mentioned as a part of my pom file.
Once the POM was made to point to the correct repository, all my classes had their compilation issues resolved.

To check if your repositories are being connected to, go to File -> Settings -> Maven -> Repositories

Here, your indexed maven repositories should be connected to successfully. If they are not, then intelliJ will not be able to resolve most 3rd party and module dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm embarrassed to say, but we also had this problem, but it was due to a mistake in our package name.

When creating the packages for a new project I accidentally created a package called "org.package".

My project then had a directory structure like:

> /src/main/java/org.package/

Which caused all sorts of havoc with IntilliJ.

Once the correct folder structure was created on the file system, IntelliJ worked great.

> /src/main/java/org/package/

Note the difference in /org.package/ vs /org/package/

Answer (score 0):

The fix was i made it javac instead of Ajc and i put 1.8 of course according to your jdk version.

for some reason when i invalidate and restart intellij it was set to be the default !

[image: after i fixed i made it javac instead of Ajc]

my version is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me...what fixed it was realising there was an extra main.iml file in the source directory. Deleting that instantly made the compile errors go away.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me.

In my case, I had to finally create an explicit Maven Run Configuration for the module (with Command Line as "clean install") and then run it.

It is in `Run > Edit Configurations`

Answer (score 0):

1. close the project
2. go-to the project folder and delete idea project file and .iws file
3. run mvn idea:idea
4. restart the project.

seems idea keeping the old project dependencies without cleaning even though we run file -> invalidate caches

Answer (score 0):

Setting the proper Java SDK solves the issue

- Right click on the project and select "Open Module Settings"
- Check if you have the right Java SDK under platform settings
  [image]
- Check the SDK under Modules
  [image]
- Rebuild the project from "Build" menu

Answer (score 0):

Delete the installation directory.

Remove the following directories:

> ~/.config/JetBrains/
>
> ~/.cache/JetBrains/
>
> ~/.local/share/JetBrains/

This will remove each and every configuration plus installation of jetbrains tools, be it IDEA, goland,etc.
Now install everything from scratch.
That's the only way it worked for me